# How to calculate average for the calendar year

Tags: date, matrix, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

My [input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylunP.png) consists of column `Actual Exp` and `Actual Min`.

Now I want to create a measure for calculating the average for the current calendar year having the latest month of data for `Actual Exp` and `Actual Min`.

I want to calculate the average from Jan'21 to Mar'21, and later if data gets added for Apr or May I would like to calculate the average from Jan'21 to May'21 or Apr'21.

Similarly, I want to have from Jan '21 to Dec'21 in Dec'21 and an average from Jan'22 to Feb'22 in Feb'22. I also have a `date` filter I don't want my date filter to affect the average.

I tried using `TOTALYTD` and `MAX(Date)`, but it's not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've not fully understood your question, but hopefully this helps:

```
AVERAGEX ( ALL(TABLENAME), TABLENAME[COLUMNNAME])
```

This should give you an average of COLUMNNAME no matter what filters/slicing you have in place.
If you wanted to futher restrict this, you can try creating a 2nd measure such as

```
CALCULATE(AVERAGEX ( ALL(TABLENAME), TABLENAME[COLUMNNAME]), datetable[monthcolumn] IN {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar"})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want the measure to calculate average for the new data also, as the new data gets added it should display the average for those new data also.

Comment: @user8078111 just remove the datetable[monthcolumn] IN {values} bit. and it'll give you the average to everything.  I got the impression you wanted it just for those 3 months as well. (so two measures)